Reference request The support of $f$-nef divisor
I'm seaching for a proof of the theorem below.
Do you know any reference?
Consider $f:X\rightarrow Y$ projective birational map between normal varieties and $\mathbb{R}$ cartier divisor $D$ whose support is contained in the exceptional set of $f$  .
If the exceptional set is connected and $D$ is non zero
$f$-nef,
Then the support of $D$ is equal to the exceptional set of $f$ and all of coefficient of $D$ is negative.

This is Lemma 3.39 of Koll'ar--Mori. There the result is stated for $\mathbb Q$-divisors but the proof seems to work just as well for $\mathbb R$-divisors.
